# (Javascript - Arrays) Get most left and most right connected character

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array (2d-matrix) and I'd like to get the x/y values for the

- most left & top connected '1'-character
- most right & bottom connected '1'-character

> EDIT 2.0:

I call my function with the parameters x/y, that are the coordinates of my start-'1'-character.

```
10001
00001
11111
01110   --> (x: 1, y: 3)
```

And my function checks the column above & and the column right so if there is a character '1' it counts x or y (wherever the column has been found) plus 1.

---

My function starts at a specific point (e.g. y: 2, x: 0)

---

```
var array = [
 '00000',
 '01111',       --> get position of the most top & right '1'-character (x: 4, y: 1)
 '11000',
 '00000'
]
```

This is the function to get the top-right end of '1'-characters:

```js
var array = [
 '00000',
 '01111',      
 '11000',
 '00000'
]
  
  
  Array.prototype.get_top_right = function(x_pos, y_pos) {
    var matrix = this, y1= y_pos;
    for (var x1 = x_pos; x1 < this[0].length; x1++) {
      try {
        if (matrix[(y1-1)][x1] == '1') y1--;
        else if (matrix[y1][(x1+1)] != '1') break;
      } catch(e) {}
    }; return [x1,y1]
 }
 
 var result=array.get_top_right(0,2)
 
 console.log(result)
```

Ok. The function above seems to work fine, but now I'd like to turn around the process to get the last bottom-left connected '1'-character of my array / 2D-matrix.

```
var array = [
  '00000',
  '01111',      
  '11000', --> get position of the most bottom & left '1'-character (x: 0, y: 2)
  '00000'
]
```

I have no clue how to edit the function above to get the left&bottom match as result instead of the most right&top match like you can see above.

> Edit 1.0 My function I've coded till yet is not working but looks like this:

```
Array.prototype.get_bottom_left = function(x_pos, y_pos) {
    var matrix = this, y2= y_pos;
    for (var x2 = x_pos; x2 > 0; x2--) {
      try {
        if (matrix[(y2+1)][x2] == '1') y2++;
        if (matrix[y2][(x2-1)] != '1') break;
      } catch(e) {}
    }; return [x2,y2]
 }
```

> Using this function above and the error_array below to get the bottom left connected character of the array will lead to a browser crash. Nice!

```
  var error_array = [
    '000000',
    '000011',
    '111110',
    '111111'
  ]
```

However, I hope somebody can help me updating my function...

Thanks a million in advance, 
*Greetings* - hans.

Comment: I could have sworn I saw this identical question yesterday, but now it's nowhere to be found, imagine that.

Comment: Ok. Sounds crazy, so if you found the question it would be super nice if you could provide the link for the question to me. Thanks!

Comment: Is the string always 5 characters?

Comment: If you mean the length of the several strings in the array, yeah the length is identical to all of them. Let's say 5.

Comment: I would recommend an array of array of booleans, not an array of strings.

Comment: For each of the other directions, all you do is to reverse the direction of one or both iterations for `x1` and `y1`.

Comment: But thats not solving my problem @Bergi

Comment: It's not working this way @Prune. I will edit a code sample in my question that is not working with my function. Wait.

Comment: Excellent idea ... [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: My code is updated in my question. Just look above. @Prune

Comment: Better, but we also want the trace-back, including the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I created two versions of `get_bottom_left` method:

- `bottom_left_up` which traversing from (x, y) point to the left and to the up
- `bottom_left_down` which traversing from (x, y) point to the right and to the down.

Here's the implementation:

```
Array.prototype.bottom_left_up = function(x, y) {
  if(this[y][x] === '0') {
    return;
  }
  while(y >= 0) {
    while(--x >= 0) {
      if(this[y][x] === '0') {
        return [x + 1, y];
      }
    }
    if(--y === -1 || this[y][this[y].length - 1] === '0') {
      return [0, y + 1];
    }
    x = this[y].length;
  }
};

Array.prototype.bottom_left_down = function(x, y) {
  if(this[y][x] === '0') {
    return;
  }
  while(y < this.length) {
    if(this[y].indexOf('0', x) !== -1) {
      return [x, y];
    }
    if(++y === this.length || this[y][0] === '0') {
      return [x, y - 1];
    }
    x = 0;
  }
};
```

You see, there are no out-of-range protections, it could be added with no problem separately. Let's test the logic:

```
var array = [
 '00000',
 '01111',
 '11000',
 '00000'
];
console.log(array.bottom_left_up(2, 1)); // [1, 1]
console.log(array.bottom_left_down(2, 1)); // [0, 2]

var array2 = [
  '000000',
  '000011',
  '111110',
  '111111'
];
console.log(array2.bottom_left_up(3, 3)); // [0, 3]
console.log(array2.bottom_left_down(3, 3)); // [3, 3]
```

Regarding methods protection, I would not use `try-catch`, I would suggest something like:

```
function(x, y) {
  x = parseInt(x, 10);
  y = parseInt(y, 10);
  if(!this.length || isNaN(x) || isNaN(y) || x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= this.length || y >= this[0].length) {
    return;
  }
  // ...
}
```

So you will get 'undefined' in 3 cases: empty array, bad params, not found.

Comment: You are absolutely right with the try-catch part & 1. - Thanks for your code, but thats not exactly the result I'd like to get. My start parameters (x/y) are at an index where is a '1' character. ---------> This is the result I'd like to get like I've mentioned in the function in my question above:  `var array = [
   '00000',
   '01111',
   '11000',
   '00000'
  ]`

`console.log(array.top_right(0, 2)); // --> [4,1]`
`console.log(array.bottom_left(2, 1)); // [0, 3]`

Comment: @pete234 Sorry, I didn't undersand the requirements properly. Even now I'm not sure... By the way, I updated my answer and provided two different versions for `get_bottom_left` method. They traverse a matrix in different directions: left+down and right+up. The same logic could be repeated for `get_top_right` method.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a function that seems to do the trick with any size of a matrix but I'm not quite sure if you wanted always to find the first "1" in the matrix  even if it was alone on the line and on the right side..
Using your arrays as test parameters

```
    var array = [
    '00000',
    '01111',       
    '11000',
    '00100'];

var error_array = [
    '000000',
    '000011',
    '111111',
    '111111',
    '000000',
    '000010',
    '100000'
    ] 


getLeftBottom(error_array);

function getLeftBottom(testArray)
{
    var firstFound;
    for (var index = testArray.length; index > 0; index--)
    {
        console.log(testArray[index-1]);
        str = testArray[index-1];
        firstFound = str.indexOf("1");
        if (firstFound !== -1)
        {
            console.log("Coordinates: x = {0}, y = {1}", firstFound, index)   // Apparently this doesn't work as I expected in JS but you can still see the coordinates
            break;
        }

    }
}
```